# Multiset erasing only one instance

Tags: c++, c++11, stl

```
for(auto it = prefixSet.begin();it!=prefixSet.end();it++)
    {
        string str = *it;
        if(prefixSet.count(str) > 1)
        {
            cout << prefixSet.count(str) << " " << str << endl;
            prefixSet.erase(it);
            cout << prefixSet.count(str) << " " << str << endl;
        }
    }
```

Prefixset is a multiset which has a string "d". After executing above code, I get the following output.

```
3 d
2 d
```

I was expecting it to delete all the instances and count to be 0.

What is that I am missing?

Comment: Erase by key instead of by iterator.

Comment: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/set/multiset/erase/
This mentions that iterator should work.

Comment: It says *Iterator pointing to a single element to be removed from the multiset.*, which is exactly what your code does.

Comment: @AnupBuchke cppreference is often clearer than the (IMO) inferior cplusplus.com: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/multiset/erase

Comment: @BaummitAugen. You can't be more right! Thanks. I will shift-delete cplusplus.com